# Investigate the solution (no solution, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions) according to the constant $a$ and $b.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Investigate the solution (no solution, a unique solution, or infinitely many solutions) of the following  system of differential equations according to the constants $a$ and $b$.

$$\begin{align*} x + bz &= 1 \\ \\
ax + y + z &= a+1 \\ \\
bx -a^2y + a^3bz &= a-a^3 \end{align*}$$

I tried to solve the problem by checking whether $\det A$ is $0$ or not. Shortly, I don't get the meaning of what I should do. If you can give any ideas for this simple question, I'll be so happy. Sincerely, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what all of the variables mean? For example, I assume that $a$ and $b$ are fixed real numbers and $x, y,$ and $z$ are indeterminate. I also fear that these are not differential equations. **Edit:** Oh, I see now that $a$ and $b$ are constant.

Comment: Yes it's not a differential equation. But it was written on the sheet and I think it was mistake. sure a and b are fixed (constant) numbers. I couldn't solve and didn't get the meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our system of equations gives rise to the matrix equation $A \mathbf x = \mathbf b,$ where we have that $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \phantom - 0 & b \\ a & \phantom - 1 & 1 \\ b & -a^2 & a^3 b \end{pmatrix},$$ $\mathbf x = (x, y, z)^t,$ and $\mathbf b = (1, a + 1, a - a^3)^t.$ Consider the induced augmented matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & \phantom - 0 & b & 1 \\ a & \phantom - 1 & 1 & a + 1 \\ b & -a^2 & a^3 b & a - a^3 \end{array} \end{pmatrix}.$$ By performing elementary row operations, we obtain the augmented matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & b & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 - ab & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & a^2 - b^2 & a + a^2 - a^3 - b \end{array} \end{pmatrix}.$$ Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: really really ! thanks . here is what the point I wanted to do. then I determine the value whether defined for z, x , y ! thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could get you started.